# Can the Import command be invoked via the Design Automation API?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm trying to invoke the AutoCAD Import command via the Design Automation API. This works fine from accoreconsole.exe locally, and while the Design Automation API accepts the Import command without error, it proceeds to the next command without importing anything.

In the excerpt of a Design Automation API output log below I'm invoking the Import command both directly from the generated script file and via SendStringToExecute via my plug-in. In the latter case I've pulled the full local file path.

```
[10/19/2017 06:20:18] Command: Import
[10/19/2017 06:20:18] Enter import file name: "input.stp"
[10/19/2017 06:20:18] Command: ProcessChamberDrawingCloud
[10/19/2017 06:20:19] Command: (command "Import" "\"T:\\Aces\\Jobs\\f4ba423419294f7eacf0d9fac71e790f\\input.stp\"")
[10/19/2017 06:20:19] Import
[10/19/2017 06:20:19] Enter import file name: "T:\Aces\Jobs\f4ba423419294f7eacf0d9fac71e790f\input.stp"
[10/19/2017 06:20:19] Command: _.quit
```

Comment: Let me check with our Design Automation team about it. Will get back to you as soon as I hear from them, thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

For STEP files, the IMPORT command depends upon the AcTranslators.exe and several atf*.dll files.  Does your environment have those files, will be the 1st question? But I'm still checking if there is some other approach.

Comment: I'm not doing anything special to embed them into the environment at present; I was under the impression that the version of accoreconsle used by the Design Automation API would have the same capabilities as it does when executed from a workstation with AutoCAD installed. Is it possible to enable IMPORT capability by including AcTranslators.exe and related atf*dll files with my AppPackage and by specifying AcTranslators.exe as an AllowedChildProcess for the Activity?

Comment: Hi Rob, Can you share the script you are trying to use, it seems what I suggested about the acTranslator.exe is already part of the Design Automation API, so something with your script might be causing this problem.

Comment: When you say script what are you looking for? I can zip up my VS project and send it to you via email or I could pull out specific items and post them here. Are there some instructions somewhere with regard to how to invoke the acTranslater via the Design Automation API?

Answer (score 0):

The 'IMPORT' command in Forge Design Automation have some problem, it doesn't spawn "AcTranslator.exe" process. we are working on some other alternative, we will keep you posted.

IMPORT is a two step process in AutoCAD

1. First it will spawn a child process like this AcTranslator.exe -i
   "input.stp" -o "output.dwg"
2. When translation is done, a notification is sent to user in the
   AutoCAD UI [Right Most corner of AutoCAD Main Window] when you click
   on the notificaton bar, translated entities from output.dwg are merged in to current
   drawing.

Currently, we see problem at first step.

**edited**
We have fixed this problem:
I have answered in another stack over flow post [Import-In-Forge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51497781/2919353)