# What input file types does the Forge Design Automation API (AutoCAD) accept?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I cannot find any resource similar to the Model Derivative API that has a list of supported file translations.

can the autocad Design Automation API take in .dxf, pdfs, etc., or is there a list somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Design Automation for AutoCAD can process DWG,DXF,DWT and DWS, unlike Model Derivative which has translation capabilities, Design Automation is a service to run automated jobs.
At the moment, importing PDF in Design Automation for AutoCAD is not possible.

Comment: Having said this, using Design Automation it is possible to use Import command to convert one format to another format for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51496188/how-can-i-create-an-activity-for-data-conversion-in-design-automation-api/51497781#51497781)
If you have specific questions on this, you can write to forge[dot]help[at]autodesk[dot]com